# What's the relation between basis for a vector space and coordinate systems?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems, change-of-basis

I know what's a basis for some vector space $V$: a set of objects from that space that *span* the whole space.

We can change between basis by using the *change of basis* matrix. Basically this matrix transforms a vector representation with respect to a basis to another representation with respect to a new basis.

I'm now wondering what's the relation between a basis of a vector space and a coordinate system for that same vector space?

Comment: A basis is **not** what you say it is as "the set of ""objects"" in that space" (i.e., the set of **vectors**) must be linearly independent besides being a generator of the whole space. Choosing a basis is the same as choosing a set of coordinates for the space, and every vector's coordinates is the column (or row) n-dimensional vector (with $\;n=\dim V$) of coefficients of the vector when represented as linear combination of the basis elements

Answer (score 6):

In a (finite dimensional) vector space (over a field), one cannot talk about coordinates without referring to a basis.

Given an ordered basis, you have a corresponding "coordinates system" by *definition*:

> Given a [**basis**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) of a vector space $V$, every element of $V$ can be expressed uniquely as a linear combination of basis vectors, whose coefficients are referred to as vector **coordinates** or **components**.